# Are there infinitely many primes next to very powersmooth numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $f(n)$ be the largest prime-power factor of $n$. Are there infinitely many primes $p$ where $f(p-1) \le p^{o(1)}$?

Candidates would be [primordial primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime) and [factorial primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime). A quick calculation using prime number theorem type bounds shows that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there must be infinitely many primes with $f(p-1) \le p^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$.

Comment: This is still an open problem, although it is believed to be true. [Here is one paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03283539/document) that cites the main references in its opening paragraphs. (They consider the largest prime factor, but the largest prime-power factor would follow the same distributions.)

Comment: That answers my question, thanks!